# IntelliJ IDEA default gradle run configuration arguments

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

When running a JUnit test with IDEA 2020.3.2 with a gradle project by right clicking a class->Run, IDEA creates a run configuration with the Arguments: `--test "class.to.execute.test" --scan`.

I don't want the `--scan` option as default argument...how can I disable that this option is not set by default?

Comment: I don't have  this option by default. Please check "Run/Debug Configurations - Templates - Gradle".

Comment: "Run/Debug Configurations - Templates - Gradle" is completely blank...so nothing preconfigured here.

Comment: Could you please add more information about your project type? Is it Java or Kotlin, Spring or Android?

Comment: It's a java Project

Comment: Is it possibel to share idea.log ("Help | Show Log in...") after restarting IDE?

Comment: Interesting, now the --scan option is no more automatically set for new configurations. I'll keep an eye on it. Problems resolving themself are the best ^^